# Very poor cgminer result on EC2 GPU with litecoin

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration, hashpower, scrypt

I have started to test mining litecoin on amazon for the fun of it .

I used [this link](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=169377.0) to start going, so I use [cgminer](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer). 
every thing went pretty fine, just that I had to use cgminer 3.0.1 to aligned with the post.

The problem is that I get very poor result - ~90Kh/s from both GPU. according to the post it should be ~190MH.

if there some configuration in order to unleash the power of the GPU ?
does cgminer have some configuration that were skiped in the link above ?

I read [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8182/litecoin-mining-10-times-slower-then-a-couple-of-days-ago) but it's not relevant since I only install cgminer.

I use the command line from the link :

```
cgminer -o http://pool:port -u user -p pass -I 11 -v 2 --shaders 448 --scrypt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misreading the post. It does not claim to get anywhere near 190MH with the command line you used. It claims to get 190MH doing SHA256d mining. Scrypt mining is, by design, over a thousand times slower than SAH256d mining.